# Block android watch batery ambient mode

Tags: java, android, wear-os, ambient, watchface

There is an ambient state that my watch goes into when it is on the charger that dims slightly but keeps the normal color depth.

And another ambient mode that the watch enters on battery with reduced color depth.

Some of the colors on my ambient palate are brighter in the reduced depth, others go black and do not show.

Is there a way to force the ambient mode that does not reduce the color depth?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to force the ambient mode that does not reduce the color depth?**

I think not. It would help if we have an idea what's happening when an Android Watch goes to Ambient mode.

> [Ambient
>   mode](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html) 
>   helps the device conserve power. Your design should make clear to the
>   user that the screen is in ambient mode. The background color scheme
>   is strictly limited to black, white, and grays. Your watch face may
>   use some color elements on screens that support it provided it is
>   unambiguous that the device is in ambient mode. You can use color
>   elements for up to 5 percent of total pixels. In this mode, the screen
>   is only updated once every minute. Only show hours and minutes in
>   ambient mode; do not show seconds. Your watch face is notified when
>   the device switches to ambient mode, and you should thoughtfully
>   design for it.

So, your watch losing the vivid colors in Ambient mode is it's way of conserving battery power.
You can also read more about Ambient mode [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html#).